# Why are other machines not returning "true" for OAuthWebSecurity.Login() with Google OAuth After Already Registered from One Computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I have a quirky little error that only occurs when machines try to login through Google OAuth after already having been registered with our site from another machine.

I have a partial CMS that only our employees can login to with one simple button click (although it is a public site for the non-CMS parts).

Everything about the login seems to work fine, but once "registered", that is, there is already an existing account in our database, and the user tries to login from a different computer the C# `if(registered)` equates to false, and treats the user as if they are trying to register, and not just login, which is handled by my code to show an error page that says something like, "That user is already registered".

The logical branch in question:

```
bool registered = OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

if (registered)
{
    Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
    return;
}
```

Here is the entire cshtml file:

```
@{
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    string email = "";
    string loginData = "";
    string providerDisplayName = "";
    var errorMessage = "";
    var db = Database.Open("Accounts");

    var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    if (returnUrl.IsEmpty())
    {
        returnUrl = Href("~/CMS Interface/AdminLogin.cshtml");
    }

    if (IsPost && Request.Form["newAccount"].AsBool())
    {
        email = Request.Form["userName"];
        loginData = Request.Form["loginData"];

        string provider = "";
        string providerUserId = "";

        if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated || !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(loginData, out provider, out providerUserId))
        {
            Context.RedirectLocal("~/");
            return;
        }

        providerDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(provider).DisplayName;

        db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email, IPAddress) VALUES (@0, @1)", email, Request.UserHostAddress);

        Roles.AddUserToRole(email, "Locked");

        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(providerDisplayName, providerUserId, email);
        OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

        Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        var result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Href("~/Account/RegisterService", new { returnUrl }));

        if (result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            bool registered = OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

            if (registered) //This doesn't equate to true after user is already registered, although it should.
            {
                Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
                return;
            }

            email = result.UserName;

            if (!EmailValidator.IsEmailAdress(email))
            {
                errorMessage = "The email address supplied was not a valid email address. ";
                errorMessage += "Please return to the main page and try again. If the problem ";
                errorMessage += "persists, please notify a site administrator for help.<br/><br/>";
                errorMessage += "<a class=\"retreatLink\" href=\"/\">Main Page</a>";
            }

            if (!email.EndsWith("@okmcity.net"))
            {
                errorMessage = "Your email address was valid, however, it seems that it's ";
                errorMessage += "not a \"City of Okmulgee\" email address. Please ensure that ";
                errorMessage += "your email address is part of the \"@okmcity.net\" domain.<br/><br/>";
                errorMessage += "If you are having trouble changing your email address ";
                errorMessage += "try visiting Google's <a href=\"https://mail.google.com\">Gmail</a> ";
                errorMessage += "page and logging out. After you have logged out of gmail, revisit ";
                errorMessage += "the <a href=\"/\">main page</a> and click the ";
                errorMessage += "\"Log-in!\" button again. Then, when prompted by Gmail services, ";
                errorMessage += "log back in using a valid \"okmcity.net\" email address.<br/><br/>";
                errorMessage += "For more help visit <a href=\"https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?hl=en\">";
                errorMessage += "Gmail Help</a> for quick steps on how to log-out of your Gmail account.";
            }

            if (errorMessage == "")
            {
                email = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf("@"));
            }

            var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);

            if (user != null)  //This branch equates to true when user is already registered (as it should, as a failsafe, except that the code should never reach this far down in the first place when a user is registered.
            {
                errorMessage = "The user " + email + " already exists. You cannot register twice. ";
                errorMessage += "Please revisit the <a href=\"/\">main page</a> and click the \"Log-in!\" ";
                errorMessage += "button again. If this problem persists, please notify a site administrator ";
                errorMessage += "for help.";
            }

            loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
            providerDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
        }
        else
        {
            Context.RedirectLocal("~/Account/ExternalLoginFailure");
            return;
        }
    }
}

<div class="subWrapper">
    <h2>Associate your @providerDisplayName account.</h2>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="loginData" value="@loginData" />
        <fieldset class="regBox">
            <legend class="regBox">Registration</legend>
            @if (errorMessage == "")
            {
                <p>
                    You've successfully authenticated with <strong>@providerDisplayName</strong>. Please
                    click the &quot;Confirm&quot; button to log-in and finish registering.
                </p>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <label for="userName">Your User Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" readonly="true" value="@email" />
                    </span>
                </div><br/>
                <button type="submit" class="loginBtn" name="newAccount" value="true">Confirm</button>
            }
            else
            {
                <p class="errorMessage">
                    @Html.Raw(errorMessage)
                </p>
            }
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

The thing is though, on the original machines, everything works fine and the `if(registered)` condition equates to true, once registered.

You'll have to forgive me, I don't know that much about OAuth. Although, I have worked with it before, I mostly tried to understand it just by reading it as I typed it, line-by-line, and occasionally looking up MSDN for help on what some of the methods do.

I had to rework the default setup for this to our specific needs, although the code is mostly the same. It is possible that I just messed something up here.

After trying to Google this and search here of SO, I was unable to find anything relevant. Also, I really don't understand the nature of this problem, so I don't know if I've left out any info that would be useful for troubleshooting this problem. If so, just let me know.

**Things You May Want To Know**

Google is the only OAuth (or openID) authentication we require.

I am working in an ASP.NET Web-Pages with Webmatrix (C#) environment.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw exactly the same problem and it was caused by WebDeploy replacing the database connection strings during the deployment (it asks me to choose them for some reason, even though they are already specified in web.config). Somehow I was only offered two values for my three connection strings, which meant one of them was wrong - the one that is used for user accounts. This means when it looks for the user ID of the person who has logged in, the whole thing fails (the table is not even there!) and somehow that error is suppressed and just returns false.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't really looked into it any more. I'm not sure if there was something in the way I had specified the connection strings so that WebDeploy only picked up two of them. Perhaps it was because on didn't have a fully qualified server name or perhaps because two were pointing to the same server. I would hope it is something silly like that rather than a major issue.